# How set id_tax, rate in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop

I want integrate payement with card in prestashop, but id_tax, tax, rate is NULL and when I redirect to payu, appears error: 'invalid account'.This is the code where select the products from cart:

```
foreach ($products as $key => $product)
    {
          $PName[] = str_replace('"', '\'', $product['name']);
          $PCode[]        =  $product['id_product'];
         // $PPrice[] = $q['product_price_no_tva'] + $q['product_price_no_tva']*$q['product_markup']/100;
          $PPrice[] = number_format(Tools::convertPrice($product['price'], $currency), 2, '.', '');
          $PQTY[] = $product['quantity'];
          $PVAT[] = $product['rate']; ''
        '
     }
    var_dump($product);
    die();
```

---

```
array(52) { ["id_product_attribute"]=> string(1) "0" ["id_product"]=> string(4) "5376" ["id_customization"]=> NULL ["cart_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["customization_quantity"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(28) "Liv 52 DS x 60 cp - Himalaya" ["description_short"]=> string(59) "

Mai usor de administrat ! O tableta cu putere dubla.
" ["available_now"]=> string(0) "" ["available_later"]=> string(0) "" ["id_category_default"]=> string(2) "14" ["id_supplier"]=> string(3) "213" ["id_manufacturer"]=> string(3) "201" ["on_sale"]=> string(1) "0" ["ecotax"]=> string(8) "0.000000" ["additional_shipping_cost"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["available_for_order"]=> string(1) "1" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> float(27.5) ["weight"]=> string(1) "0" ["width"]=> string(1) "0" ["height"]=> string(1) "0" ["depth"]=> string(1) "0" ["out_of_stock"]=> string(1) "2" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" ["date_add"]=> string(19) "2012-06-21 11:41:29" ["date_upd"]=> string(19) "2013-03-18 17:00:19" ["minimal_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["id_tax"]=> NULL ["tax"]=> NULL ["rate"]=> NULL ["price_attribute"]=> NULL ["quantity_attribute"]=> NULL ["ecotax_attr"]=> NULL ["link_rewrite"]=> string(29) "liv-52-ds-cpr-x-60-himalayaca" ["category"]=> string(23) "afectiuni-hepatobiliare" ["unique_id"]=> string(5) "53260" ["reference"]=> string(6) "W51645" ["supplier_reference"]=> string(0) "" ["weight_attribute"]=> NULL ["ean13"]=> string(0) "" ["upc"]=> string(0) "" ["pai_id_image"]=> NULL ["pai_legend"]=> NULL ["stock_quantity"]=> int(5) ["price_wt"]=> float(27.5) ["total_wt"]=> float(27.5) ["total"]=> float(27.5) ["id_image"]=> string(7) "5376-14" ["legend"]=> string(34) "Liv 52 DS-cpr. x 60 - Himalaya(CA)" ["reduction_applies"]=> bool(false) ["allow_oosp"]=> int(0) ["features"]=> array(0) { } }
```